# How to write .bat for Windows task scheduler to run my Sikuli?

Tags: batch-file, automation, scheduler, sikuli

I have developed an automation script by using Sikuli. Now, I want the Windows task scheduler to run my script, say download.sikuli at 12 p.m. every day.

I know how to set scheduler but how should I write the .bat code?

Comment: Not sure what bat code you're referring to?

Comment: I dont know either. I just want my Windows to automate my sikuli script but it seems like the Windows Task Scheduler needs a .bat (batch) file to run my sikuli.

Comment: [HowTo run Sikuli on a Windows machine …](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/2220)

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\SikuliX\runsikulix.cmd -r "C:\Users\your_name\Desktop\sikuli_folder\download.sikuli"
```

Put that in a .txt, save as .bat. First directory is where your sikuli.cmd file is located, second directory is where your xyz.sikuli folder is located.

<sub>Note that for my directories I do not have any spaces, the quotes around the directory path are included for good measure if your directories do contain spaces.</sub>

Comment: If you want to reference directories that have spaces between names, you could enclose the sentences with **"**